# How can we use all the functionalities of TortoiseGit through browser?

Tags: git, web, interface, tortoisegit

I am using Git as version control tool and TortoiseGit for managing my repos.

But I need to know whether it is possible to use all the functionalities of TortoiseGit through browser as Web Interface.
It should be a free source if it is possible.

Comment: Would you be trying to view your local git repository, or view a central one (on a server, for instance)? What is the purpose? (You may also consider [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/whats-the-best-web-interface-for-git-repositories)).

Answer (score 0):

Since 2012, [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) still offer *local* repo management.

You would use a web interface to manage *remote* repos (ie ones which are not on your computer)
Typically, open-source web client for Git hosting servers would be [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), [Gogs](https://gogs.io/), [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-US/), [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/), ...

But they are not providing exactly the same kind of feature as TortoiseGit: they won't give you the local status of your repo.

For that, you might consider another client, based on web technology: [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), recently (May 2017) redesigned with [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/).
Electron allows for the development of desktop GUI applications using front and back end components originally developed for [web applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application): [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) runtime for the backend and [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) for the frontend. (source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)))